# How to save dataframe with loop that produces NaN as output?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, output

I have written a function random_sample() where the output is a large dataframe with 2 row and 751 rows. Every time I run the function there is a novel data frame see below.

> W_332     W_333     W_334  ...    W_1066    W_1067    W_1068    W_1069  
> 0  0.098432  0.094451  0.096085  ...  0.090937  0.068576  0.085326  0.095416
> 1  0.164170  0.197848  0.161228  ...  0.272259  0.283551  0.229989  0.230067
> [2 rows x 751 columns]

When I run the following code

```
    for g in range(5):
    sample = random_sample()
    ref = {g:sample}
    empt_dict.append(ref)
df_pd = pd.DataFrame(empt_dict)
df_pd
```

I get the following table as my output but I can see all of the 5 dataframes of the above [2 rows x 751 columns] repeated with a novel set of numbers but not together

0      1       2       3       4

0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

1  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

2  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

3  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

4  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

How do I save the 5 iterative 2 by 751 from my function? Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the sample fucntion?

Comment: It is quite long and this is a sample I turned this code into the function[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73644975/how-to-write-a-loop-random-selected-data-and-where-the-output-is-continuous-data]
`#Calculations 
collist = list(gdf.columns)
emptydict = []
for j in collist[14:]:
    B1 = (((gdf.groupby(['Category1'])['Category2'].sum())/(gdf['Category2'].sum())) *  
            (gdf.groupby(['Category1'])[j].mean())).sum()
    res = {j:B1}
    emptydict.append(res)
resdf = pd.DataFrame(emptydict)
resdf1 = resdf.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values))
resdf1
return resdf1`